# Pattern for dynamically setting an order based on contents of a std::vector<string>

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

I am currently struggling coming up with an optimized method for dynamic ordering. I currently have a vector that looks like this in some place of my code

```
std::vector<std::string> vec {
      "optionB",
      "optionA",
      "optionC"
  };
```

The items in the above vector can be shuffled.The items in this vector are inserted in a specific order so the above order can be different. For simplicity sakes I added the items during declaration.There are about 9 items in the actual case for simplicity I am using only 3 string items.

Now somewhere else in my code I have something like this.

```
void filter() 
{
  bool _optionA,_optionB,_optionC
  ...
  //These boolean variables get assigned values
  ...
  ...

  /*
  Todo : I would like to change the ordering of the 
  following code based on the ordering of items in the 
  vector. Currently its in the order _optionA _optionB, 
  _optionC. I would like this ordering to be based
  on the order of the strings as in the above vector. 
  so it should be _optionB,_optionA,_optionC ,
  I understand the items in the vector are string 
  and the following are boolean types
  */

  if(_optionA){
  }
  if(_optionB) {
  }
  if(_optionC){
  }
}
```

The simplest approach that comes to my mind is

```
    for(auto str : vec) 
    {
      if( (str=="optionA" && _optionA))
       {
          //This was optionA
       }
       else if( (str=="optionB" && _optionB)) {

       }
       else if( (str=="optionC" && _optionC)) {

       }
   }
```

I want to know what would be the most optimized way to accomplish the above task ? I am looking for a solution that would avoid iterating through a vector since its in a performance centric piece of code. Is there a way for me to use integrate bitwise operations or something like array indexing to accomplish this task ? Please let me know if something is unclear

Comment: How many items do you expect? if its relatively small not very large. You could provide 1 vector defining your custom order and in the other vector insert items based on your the lookup of that order. I beleive you are after a custom sort

Comment: I think I don't understand the question. Do you want to have specific order of your `if` conditions (dependent on the order of elements in vector)? Something like `std::map<std::string, bool> conditions; std::vector<std::string> order; for (const auto& elem : order) { if (conditions[elem]) {doSth();} }` ?

Comment: @Ptaq666 yes i could do that but I am looking for an even optimized solution. I would like to avoid iterations

Comment: @SamerTufail I would like to avoid vector iterations in the filter function due to performance reasons

Comment: If you are 100% sure that this might affect performance in a significant way, it's OK. But remember what Michael A. Jackson said about code optimization.

Comment: The number of `bool`s is a compile-time constant, the size of the `std::vector` is not. However, they are intimately related. Maybe the size of your vector is also fixed and you can use `std::array` instead? Then some compile-time tricks might work.

Comment: @Rajeshwar you have to touch all the elements in order to determine which conditions are applicable to look them up. If you dont want that, maybe vector is not the right ds to start with.

Comment: @Ptaq666 I am open to using array indexing of some sort but in no way can I use vector iterations

Comment: If the vector is only loaded in once and no further items are added to it, maybe you can sort it during load or somewhere else and then just use array indexing?

Comment: The vector is loaded on startup. There is no need to sort the vector as I would like to preserve the order and use that order in the `filter` function.@FarbodD can you give an example on how I can use array indexing based on that ?

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem correctly, sorting is a way to go. Just sort the vector **together** with `bool` flags, using `std::vector` values as keys, and then simply check `bool` flags in fixed, lexicographic, order.

Suppose we have a vector `{"optB", "optC", "optA"}`. After sorting, the indices `{0, 1, 2}` will rearrange: `std::size_t perm[] = {2, 0, 1}`. Using this information, that can be precomputed (outside `filter(...)`), we can rearrange the `bool` flags:

```
bool options[N];
// populate options...

bool new_options[N];
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    new_options[perm[i]] = options[i];
```

Now we simply check `new_options` successively:

```
if (new_options[0]) {
    ...
}
if (new_options[1]) {
    ...
}
```

To precompute `perm` array use `std::map`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::size_t> map;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    map.emplace(vec[i], i);

std::size_t perm[N];
auto m = map.begin();
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i, ++m)
    perm[i] = m->second;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want map a string to an actual process. Could you create an interface option class and have instances of options mapped to the string that should cause them to occur? That way you could use the string as a key to get back an Option object and call something like myOption.execute().

The downside to this method is that you need to create a new option class and have it inherit from the interface each time you need a new option.

@Edit: Sorry I think I may have misunderstood the question. But I think the premise still applies you could have a map of string to boolean and just use the string as a key to get back whether the option is toggled on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you load the vector in on start up, you can sort it at that point to your liking. For example, in alphabetical order. This will mean that you know the order of the vector therefore you can simply reference the vector by index when checking in the your filter function.

1. Load in data into vector `std::vector<string> data = {"optionA", "optionB"};`.
2. Sort using `std::sort(data.begin, data.end);` or any other sort method of your choice.
3. Then in you filter function check the vector based on index. `if (data.at(1) == "optionA") { }`

Comment: And where should `bool _optionX` appear in this solution?

Comment: My bad misunderstood the question. Could use map in that case to map the string to a bool.

Comment: `std::map` is very slow, and OP wants speed. But I think that your point on sorting is a step in the right direction.

Comment: What's the speed difference with indexing with `std::map` and `std::vector`? Because I think if it is sorted only once on startup it wouldn't impact performance that much, because OP didn't want to loop in the actual filter function, not during startup, I believe.

Comment: You should present your code, then we can have a more meaningful discussion about speed. In general, iteration over `std::vector` is just accessing successive memory cells (very fast with caching and prefetching), and this is not the case for `std::map` that is, typically, a red-black tree.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to imply **order_by** on the boolean variables/predicates.
In the below program I will refer your (`_optionA`, `_optionB`, `_optionC`) as predicates even though they are `bool`, since we can upgrade this problem to work with predicates as well.

Based on the above assumption, I am going ahead with an implementation.

You should pass an `ordered_predicates` to your filter function.
`ordered_predicates` is sorted according to your desired criteria.
`filter()`'s job is just to execute them in the order defined.

```
auto filter(std::vector<bool> const & ordered_predicates)
    -> void
{
    for (auto const & condition : ordered_predicates) {
        if (condition) {
            // ... do your usual stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

So how should we go ahead to achieve this `ordered_predicates`?
We will create a function called `order_by` that will take an `order_by_criteria` and a `mapping`, which will help it in creating `ordered_predicates`.
With this function, creating `ordered_predicates` is just a one time cost.

```
auto order_by(std::vector<std::string>    const & order_by_criteria,
              std::map<std::string, bool> const & mapping)
    -> std::vector<bool>
{
    std::vector<bool> ordered_predicates;
    for (auto const & item : order_by_criteria)
        ordered_predicates.push_back(mapping.at(item));
    return ordered_predicates;
}
```

Where `order_by_criteria` is your `std::vector<std::string>` and `mapping` is just a map which tells which string and predicates are associated.

```
    std::vector<std::string> order_by_criteria { "optionB", "optionA", "optionC" };

    std::map<std::string, bool> mapping = { {"optionA", _optionA },
                                            {"optionB", _optionB },
                                            {"optionC", _optionC } };
```

Here is a complete working program for your reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

auto order_by(std::vector<std::string>    const & order_by_criteria,
              std::map<std::string, bool> const & mapping)
    -> std::vector<bool>
{
    std::vector<bool> ordered_predicates;
    for (auto const & item : order_by_criteria)
        ordered_predicates.push_back(mapping.at(item));
    return ordered_predicates;
}

auto filter(std::vector<bool> const & ordered_predicates)
    -> void
{
    for (auto const & condition : ordered_predicates) {
        if (condition) {
            // ... do your usual stuff here
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    bool _optionA = true, _optionB = false, _optionC = true;

    std::vector<std::string> order_by_criteria { "optionB", "optionA", "optionC" };

    std::map<std::string, bool> mapping = { {"optionA", _optionA },
                                            {"optionB", _optionB },
                                            {"optionC", _optionC } };

    auto ordered_predicates = order_by(order_by_criteria, mapping);

    filter(ordered_predicates);
    filter(ordered_predicates); // call as many times as you want, with pre-decided order 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `optionX` was a **local** variable in `filter(...)` and now it magically moved into `main(...)`.

Comment: Well the this is just a portrayal of idea. You need to de-couple the ordering criteria from the execution. That is how we can prevent its execution multiple times.